# Stopping vim putting text onto the next line automatically

Tags: unix, vim, terminal

When I type in vim it is automatically putting stuff onto the next lines for example when i have

```
Son     200 title African Art     carving Songo people    1930/12/31      1995/10/22      890     Finn    Borrowed
```

And I try adding 'the human' to Finn it does this

```
Son     200 title  African Art     
carving Songo people    1930/12/31      1995/10/22      890        Finn 
the human       Borrowed
```

It's been causing some errors if I don't manually backspace the "new lines" is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Is it adding a literal newline character, or is it displaying the text across several lines? (You could use `:se number` to help you find out)

Comment: Se number makes 3 lines instead of 1

Comment: What does `:se tw?` output?

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by either `'textwidth'` or `'wrapmargin'` option. The `'formatoptions'` option determines when exactly the wrapping happens.

As all of those options are usually set by a *filetype plugin*, you also need to inspect the current filetype. So,

```
:verbose setlocal tw? wm? fo?
```

would be a good starting point for troubleshooting. See `:help ins-textwidth` for a full explanation of the effect.